# I get force close when I start a new thread!

Tags: android, sockets, client, pthreads

I have an app in android which is something like a client server application and inside my program at a certain point I start a new thread meant to connect the client to the server.

My problem is that when I start this new thread I don't know what happens but when I try to interact with my GUI(press a button that takes me to another activity) I get force close.

It's a little bit confusing cause as I read on different web pages the new thread I start has nothing to di with my GUI so even if the client tries to connect or fails  I should be able to 
"play" with my interface.

Here is my code:

```
public class screen1 extends Activity {

private TextView clientState;
private String serverIpAddress="10.0.2.2";
public static final int ClientPort = 8080;
String message="Hello Server!";
int longitude;
int latitude;
private PrintWriter out=null;
DBAdapter db;
private Handler handler=new Handler();
Socket socket;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
    clientState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.client_Status);
```

//this is the button meant to get me to another activity and when pressed it gives me FC

```
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainMenu);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
       Intent i = new Intent(screen1.this, screen2.class);
       startActivity(i);
       } 
    });
```

//here I start a new thread defined below

```
  Thread cThread=new Thread(new ClientThread()); 

  cThread.start();  
db=new DBAdapter(this);

}
```

//here it is my client that tries to connect

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable{


    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            InetAddress serverAddr=InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    clientState.setText(" try to connect!");
                }
            });
            socket=new Socket(serverAddr,ClientPort);

            //connected=true;
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    clientState.setText("Connected!");
                }
            });

        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        db.createDatabase();
         db.openDataBase();
           Cursor c=db.getAllData();

           if(c.moveToFirst()) 
             {
              do{

                  longitude=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(1));
                  out.println(longitude);
                  latitude=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(2));
                  out.println(latitude);

              }while(c.moveToNext());

             }




        }
        catch(Exception e){
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    clientState.setText("Error");
                    }
            });

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And onStop() method:

```
protected void onStop() {

 super.onStop();

  try {

        out.close();
        socket.close();

     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
}
```

Well,this is it,for further details I'm here to explain.Thank u in advance:)

0

```
4-16 03:51:25.045: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {test.android/test.android.screen1}: java.lang.NullPointerException

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3227)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3272)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:119)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1880)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at 
test.android.screen1.onStop(screen1.java:106)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1169)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:3797)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3224)

04-16 03:51:25.074: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(242):     ... 11 more

04-16 03:51:25.144: INFO/Process(51): Sending signal. PID: 242 SIG: 3

04-16 03:51:25.154: INFO/dalvikvm(242): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3

04-16 03:51:25.204: INFO/dalvikvm(242): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

04-16 03:51:41.604: INFO/Process(242): Sending signal. PID: 242 SIG: 9

04-16 03:51:41.714: INFO/ActivityManager(51): Process test.android (pid 242) has died.

04-16 03:51:41.753: INFO/WindowManager(51): WIN DEATH: Window{43e0eb10 test.android/test.android.screen2 paused=false}

04-16 03:51:41.765: INFO/WindowManager(51): WIN DEATH: Window{43e068b0 test.android/test.android.screen1 paused=false}

04-16 03:51:41.974: INFO/ActivityManager(51): Start proc test.android for activity test.android/.screen1: pid=249 uid=10030 gids={3003}

04-16 03:51:42.433: DEBUG/ddm-heap(249): Got feature list request

04-16 03:51:42.704: INFO/UsageStats(51): Unexpected resume of test.android while already resumed in test.android

04-16 03:51:43.294: WARN/InputManagerService(51): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 242 uid 10030

04-16 03:51:43.513: INFO/ActivityManager(51): Displayed activity test.android/.screen1: 1736 ms (total 1736 ms)
```

Well,dear friends I've removed from my code the onStop() function and everything seems to work!

protected void onStop() {

```
    super.onStop();

    try {

        out.close();


        socket.close();

     } catch (IOException e) {

         e.printStackTrace();

     }
}
```

What is wrong with it?:-S

Comment: I posted the logcat as an edit to my answer but I get only one error-Attach thread failed

Comment: I've done it...I have 17 privilegies and I voted up for a few questions

Comment: This does not look like a "force close" error. You need to look for something with an excpetion somewheres

Comment: Ok,now I think I've posted the right information from the logcat!

Comment: take a look at line 242 in Screen1.  You have a NullPointerException on that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the variable `out` in your `onStop` method of the thread is `null`. You declare the variable, but you initialize it with `null` and never initialize another value to it.

You do

```
PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
```

in the `run` method of your thread, but this variable has a different scope than the variable used in your `onStop` method. That's why you get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: private PrintWriter out=null;   but after that   PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);